How to convert a list composed of lists containing one element (string) so that it is not a string but separate elements in python?
I'm trying to do a task in python where the input file is a txt file. The function is intended to extract companies from the file (1 company, 1 line) and their revenues. The company name and revenue are separated by semicolons (;). The function is supposed to return the name of the company that achieved the highest revenue and its revenue.
For examle:
input txt file:
*Company 1;5000;6000;3000;8000
*Company 2;4000;2000;3000;9000;2000
*Company 3;5000;6000;3000;8000;3000;4000;5000
*Company 4;4000;6000;4000;8000

Expected output:
The biggest revenue: Company 3
The revenue is: 34000
I've tried something like this:
def comany_with_max_revenue():
  list_of_lists = []
  with open(name_file, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
      list_of_lists.append(line.strip().split('\t'))
    print(list_of_lists)

    for company in lista_list:
      elements_of_company = company.split(";")
    print(list_of_lists)

The output is a list of lists and every list has juz one element (string with the name of company and their incomes) I don't know how to change it to string and floats and then how to find the company with the biggest revenue.

Show a sample of the input file and the corresponding expected output

There's no need to convert the numbers to float as they're all integers.
Split each line on semi-colon. The first token is the company name (with an asterisk prefix which we'll remove). The remaining tokens are all numbers that need to be added together.
Build a list of tuples (revenue, company) which you can then sort to determine the highest revenue company.
Like this:
FILENAME = "foo.txt"

def company_with_max_revenue(filename):
    data = []

    with open(filename) as f:
        for row in f:
            company, *revenues = row.split(";")
            sr = sum(map(int, revenues))
            data.append((sr, company[1:]))

    return sorted(data)[-1]

revenue, company = company_with_max_revenue(FILENAME)

print(f"The biggest revenue: {company} The revenue is {revenue}")

Output:
The biggest revenue: Company 3 The revenue is 34000

